# Android: Animation in an adapter only works inside of a clickListener, otherwise fails with Null Pointer Exception (SmallBangView)

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

The XML layout:

```
<xyz.hanks.library.bang.SmallBangView
     android:id="@+id/textViewAnimation_smallbang"
     android:layout_width="match_parent">

     <TextView
           android:id="@+id/newCount"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="0"
           android:textAlignment="center" />

</xyz.hanks.library.bang.SmallBangView>
```

The adapter:

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public SmallBangView newCountWrapper;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, int VIEW_TYPE) {
            super(itemView);

            newCountWrapper = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewAnimation_smallbang);
        }
    }
```

This **DOES NOT** work, but this is what I need:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
     holder.newCountWrapper.setSelected(true);
     holder.newCountWrapper.likeAnimation();
}
```

This however **DOES** work (it shows the animation exactly how I need it - but only onClick):

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
      holder.newCountWrapper.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                holder.newCountWrapper.setSelected(true);
                holder.newCountWrapper.likeAnimation();
            }
      });
}
```

---

Therefore, the problem is not because `holder.newCountWrapper` is null. I also tried to replace `holder.newCountWrapper.likeAnimation()` with just changing the visibility, and that works fine. So it must be something else.

So I assume it has something to do with maybe the thread and the Context and such stuff. And it does work with the onClick "environment" but not with the adapter "environment". So what can I do about this? I need the animation to start right when the item appears in the recyclerView (that is directly because it's the first item in the list), and not after a click on it.

The error message is:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setScaleX(float)' on a null object reference
        at xyz.hanks.library.bang.SmallBangView.likeAnimation(SmallBangView.java:190)
        at xyz.hanks.library.bang.SmallBangView.likeAnimation(SmallBangView.java:181)
        at com.package.MyClass.onBindViewHolder(LikeNotificationAdapter.java:120)
```

The line it is pointing to is this one: `holder.newCountWrapper.likeAnimation();`

---

The library is this one: [GitHub](https://github.com/hanks-zyh/SmallBang)

And I followed a tutorial from here: [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-an-instagram-twitter-heart-like-animation-in-android/)

Comment: Looks like that class doesn't assign at least one of its fields until `onMeasure()` runs, which won't first happen until long after the initial `onBindViewHolder()`. That's why your `OnClickListener` works, though, 'cause it's obviously measured and laid out by then. Apart from modifying the library, you could possibly do a simple workaround to delay it like so: `holder.newCountWrapper.post(() -> holder.newCountWrapper.likeAnimation());`. (It's crashing in `likeAnimation()`, btw, not `setSelected()`.)

Comment: I want that animation to happen when you open that Fragment. Without first having to click on it. You were right though, just delaying it solves it. Thanks!

Comment: Post it as an answer and I accept it :)

Comment: No problem! I'm good, however. :-) Nothin' major. Please feel free to post one yourself, if you'd like. Thank you, though. I appreciate the offer. Glad it worked for ya. Cheers!